# Almost sure uniqueness of conditional expectation

Tags: functions, random-variables, expected-value, almost-everywhere

Let $Z(t)$ and $E_N^0(f(Z(0)))$ be given as in the snippet below.
I would like to know how follows this: $$E[\lambda(0)\ | \ Z(0)]=E[\lambda(0)]$$
from the **a.s. uniqueness of the conditional expectation and from this:**
$$E_N^0[f(Z(0))] = E[f(Z(0))]$$

for all non-negative measurable functions $f:E\to \mathbb{R}$
[image]

Comment: I do not see a definition of $E_N^0[X]$ anywhere in the snippet you give.

Comment: I also cannot follow that snippet because of loaded terminology such as "$E_N^0[X]$," and "admits a $F_t$ intensity" and "flow $\theta_t$"  and "compatible with the flow $\theta_t$." They seem scary.  I assume they are defined earlier in the book.

Comment: @Michael I'm happy that someone is concerned about my question. I'm giving the book [here](http://31.42.184.140/main/1062000/ed5a0ddf5490a6d9192313a1fd959ea2/%28Applications%20of%20Mathematics%2026%29%20Fran%C3%A7ois%20Baccelli%2C%20Pierre%20Br%C3%A9maud%20%28auth.%29%20-%20Elements%20of%20Queueing%20Theory_%20Palm%20Martingale%20Calculus%20and%20Stochastic%20Recurrences-Springer-Verlag%20Berlin%20Heidelberg%20%282003%29.pdf).

Comment: @Michael I'm just interested how the formula 3.3.8. follows from **a.s. uniqueness of conditional expectation.**

Comment: I think that (3.3.8) is not a formula, it seems to be a condition.  It is similar to the condition for random variables $X$ and $Y$ being $E[X|Y]=E[X]$, which could be true for example if $X,Y$ are independent.   The expression $E[X|Y]$ is indeed something that can be talked about almost-sure uniquely by facts regarding the definition of conditional expectation.  PS:  Your question reminded me of another question about another book that found a way to make integers confusing by calling them "relative integers"...So I looked back and you were the same person!  Likely it is the same scary book.

Comment: @Michael You are completely right. You seem to udnderstand the problem, so can you tell me what's the role of the conditional $Z(0)$ in 3.3.8 ? Is there the number 0 important ? Finally, how does the equality with r.h.s. $E[\lambda(0)]$ follow from the a.s. uniqueness of conditional expectation assumption ? Also I thought that a.s. involves some **sequence** of R.V. Is this sequence present in our condition 3.3.8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For random variables $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $Y:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, we can form a new random variable $E[X|Y]:\Omega \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, called the *conditional expectation of $X$ given $Y$* (also called the conditional expectation of $X$ given the sigma algebra $\sigma(Y)$).  For details, you can google "conditional expectation given a sigma algebra."

The conditional expectation $E[X|Y]$ is always a deterministic function of $Y$, so that
$$ E[X|Y] = g(Y)$$
for some deterministic and measurable function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.  Since all random variables $X, Y$ are really functions of the outcome $\omega \in \Omega$, we can emphasize such dependency by writing $X(\omega)$ and $Y(\omega)$ and
$$ E[X|Y](\omega) = g(Y(\omega))$$

It turns out that there can be infinitely many *versions* of the conditional expectation $E[X|Y]$.  So we can have three different versions $g_1(Y)$, $g_2(Y)$, $g_3(Y)$, all valid versions of $E[X|Y]$.  So then what do we mean when we write $E[X|Y]$?  Which version do we use: $g_1(Y)$, or $g_2(Y)$, or $g_3(Y)$, or some other version?  It turns out that it does not matter since it can be proven that any two versions are the same, except possibly on a set of measure zero.  So
$$ g_1(Y(\omega)) = g_2(Y(\omega))=g_3(Y(\omega)) \mbox{ for almost all $\omega \in \Omega$} $$
where "almost all" means "except possibly on a set of measure zero."

---

This is similar in spirit to the fact that the exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda>0$ has an infinite number of PDF functions (nonnegative functions $f_X:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that satisfy $P[X\leq x] = \int_{-\infty}^x f_X(t)dt$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$), but each one of them differs from the standard one
$$ f_X(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \lambda e^{-\lambda x} & \mbox{ if $x \geq 0$} \\ 0 & \mbox{ else} \end{array}\right.$$
only on a set of measure zero. None of the integration properties are changed if we change the function value at only one point, or two points, or a set of points that has measure zero.  So the following function $\tilde{f}_X$ is also a valid PDF:
$$ \tilde{f}_X(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} \lambda e^{-\lambda x} & \mbox{ if $x \geq 0, x \neq 12.6$} \\ 42 & \mbox{ if $x=12.6$}\\ 0 & \mbox{ else} \end{array}\right.$$

---

So if we say "assume $E[X] = E[X|Y]$ almost surely" it means that $E[X|Y]$ is almost surely equal to the constant $E[X]$.  That is, all versions of $E[X|Y]$ differ from the constant $E[X]$ only on a set of measure zero.  That is, if $g(Y)$ is a version of $E[X|Y]$ then
$$ P[\omega \in \Omega : g(Y(\omega)) \neq E[X]] = 0$$

---

**Practice exercise:**
Define
$$\Omega = \{pink, yellow, green, blue\}$$ Assume all outcomes are equally likely, so \begin{align}
&P[\{pink\}]=P[\{yellow\}]= P[\{green\}] \\
&= P[\{blue\}]=1/4
\end{align}
Define $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $Y:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by
\begin{align*}
Y(pink) = 0 , \quad & X(pink) = -1\\
Y(yellow) = 0, \quad & X(yellow) = 1\\
Y(green) = 1, \quad & X(green) = -2\\
Y(blue) = 1, \quad & X(blue) = 2
\end{align*}

a) Compute the real number $E[X]$.

b) Compute the real numbers $E[X|Y=0]$ and $E[X|Y=1]$. Call these real numbers $m_0$ and $m_1$, respectively.

c) Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?  Are they uncorrelated?

d) Note that $E[X|Y]$ can be defined as follows:  Define the function
$$g(y) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
m_0 & \mbox{ if $y=0$} \\
m_1 & \mbox{ if $y=1$} 
\end{array}\right.$$
Then $E[X|Y]$ can be defined as $g(Y)$.  Is it true that $E[X|Y](\omega)=E[X]$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$?

e) Change the problem by making $\Omega = \{pink, yellow, green, blue, tan\}$, and assume
\begin{align}
P[\{pink\}]&=1/4\\
P[\{yellow\}]&= 1/4\\
P[\{green\}]&=1/4\\
P[\{blue\}]&=1/4\\
P[\{tan\}]&= 0
\end{align}
Define $X$ and $Y$ the same, except we make $X(tan) = Y(tan)=42$.  You will find that none of the expectations are different, and now $E[X|Y]$ is "almost surely" $E[X]$, and you can define infinitely many versions of $E[X|Y]$ as $g(Y)$ via the function:
$$g(y) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
m_0 & \mbox{ if $y=0$} \\
m_1 & \mbox{ if $y=1$} \\
AnythingYouWant & \mbox{ if $y=42$} 
\end{array}\right.$$
You then ask "Why do we care about part (e), since probability zero outcomes don't matter"?  Exactly.  You should not be overly concerned about part (e). The practical meat of a problem will not change if you intuitively interpret "almost surely" as "surely." You can always change a probability space by throwing away a set of outcomes that has measure zero, which reduces the sample space but has no impact on any probability or expectation.

Comment: I'm very pleased with your answer. I have a supplementary question:  which $$ g_1(Y(\omega)) = g_2(Y(\omega))=g_3(Y(\omega)) \mbox{ for almost all $\omega \in \Omega$} $$ corresponds to $$E[\lambda(0)\ |\ Z(0)]=E[\lambda(0)]$$ and to which side: r.h.s. or l.h.s. ? I.e. **what** shall I choose for $g_1(Y(\omega))$ to obtain this 3.3.8 ?

Comment: Also, is your "assume $E[X]=E[X\ |\ Y]$ almost surely" some extra assumption or does it really hold in fact ?

Comment: And finally, is the assumption of independence of $X$ and $Y$ needed ?

Comment: If $\lambda(0)$ is a random variable and $Z(0)$ is a random variable then $E[\lambda(0)|Z(0)]=g(Z(0))$ for some function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.  If we are additionally told that $E[\lambda(0)|Z(0)]=E[\lambda(0)]$, more precisely we should be told that this holds "almost surely," and this really means that  $g(x) = E[\lambda(0)]$ for "almost all" $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I have added a practice exercise on my answer, related to your question about independence. Practically, I would ignore the "almost surely" in these cases (as most people do) because it really does not contain any meaning that is directly practical and helpful.  I suspect you are chasing down the wrong phrase: You will not be empowered once you fully understand "almost surely."   Ignore it.  Just like you can practically ignore the fact that there are infinitely many PDFs for the exponential random variable.  Just use the standard one.

Comment: We are **not** told that $$E[\lambda(0)\ | \ Z(0)]=E[\lambda(0)]$$ but rather $$E_N^0[f(Z(0))] = E[f(Z(0))]$$ for all non-negative measurable $f$'s. And from this latter we need to derive: $$E[\lambda(0)\ | \ Z(0)]=E[\lambda(0)].$$ The hint is:  "it follows from the a.s. uniqueness of the conditional expectation". But I do not follow, among other things, how can I derive "the a.s. uniqueness of the conditional expectation" from what we are given.

Comment: Please re-read my very first comment "I do not see a definition of $E_N^0[X]$ anywhere," and then my second comment on how the various other expressions and phrases have loaded/undefined terminology.

Comment: But you now have the book, don't you ? $E^0_N[Z(t)]$ means the mean value of the R.V. $Z(t)$ at $t=0$ under arrival rate $N$. I think that only $0$ there matters, not the $N$. Everything else, including the hint of "a.s. uniqueness of the conditional expectation" is now the **ordinary statistics without** any referring to Queueing theory. I now treat the condition 3.3.8 as believable but not proved from ESTA.

Comment: Also, $\lambda(t)$ means $N(\{ t \})$ for $N$ (the arrival process) as given on the page 4.

Comment: Perhaps you can do the exercise I designed in my answer.  That would make me more willing to read your book, figure out all the notation, and respond accordingly.